# Show stuff only if profile owner does not belong to role X (in Drupal 7)

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I have a Drupal 7 site, and I would like to print out inside the profile page some field content, according to the role of the profile user (not the logged in user). 
I need to **show a specific field only if the profile owner does not have role** autor:

```
<?php
  if (!in_array('autor', array_values($user->roles))) {
print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['main'], 'field_nombrecompleto1', 'value'));
  }
  else {print "yada yada";}
```

Note: The profile field in question, is a rofile2 field and not a core profile one.

What´s wrong with that code? Because **it will print out the field in question in any case**, regardless of the role of the profile owner.

I´ve tried this other code, and in this case the field won´t print out in any case:

```
<?php
if (is_array($user->roles) &&
    in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles) &&
    !in_array('autor', $user->roles)) {
    print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['main'], 'field_nombrecompleto1', 'value'));
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try a print_r($user->roles), does it contain the targeted user roles?

Comment: But I don´t want to print the user roles, but to show information according to the user role of the profile.

Comment: this is a debug command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this is accomplished in Drupal 7 when modifying the form for editing your profile:

```
function MYMODULE_form_profile2_edit_main_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  global $user;
  $roles = $user->roles;
  if(!in_array('authenticated user', $roles)) {
    $form['profile_main']['MY_FIELD_ID']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```